# Why are some commandments relayed via "Tzav" but not others?

Tags: words, mitzvah, pentateuch-chumash

In the chumash, there are approximately 10 places where a law is given to the Children of Israel and is preceded by Hashem's telling Moshe to command (tzav) the people, or certain people. An example is [B'midbar 5:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "צַ֚ו אֶת־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל וִֽישַׁלְּחוּ֙"

But in many other cases, laws are conveyed with other verbs (such as "va'amarta", [Vayikra 19:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). In a few cases, both a tzav-rooted AND an amar-rooted word are used ([B'midbar 34:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.34.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Is there a difference in the nature of the law which would call for its being framed by a tzav-based word vs. any other word?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Leviticus.6.2.1?lang=bi

Comment: @JoelK I'm not sure how that works for Bmidbar 34:2 which doesn't take effect immediately, nor do some of the tzav commands seem to require more zerizut than others.

Comment: I agree it's by no means a fully fleshed out answer to your question (hence the comment). More like a starting point for further research